# BrowserHistory in Node/Express with API

Tags: node.js, express, react-router, browser-history

I am attempting to implement BrowserHistory for a React app that uses react-router. Based on [the documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md), I have in my `index.js`:

```
let express = require('express');
let harp = require('harp');
let path = require('path');

let app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"));
app.use(harp.mount(__dirname + "/dist"));

// BrowserHistory code
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

let port = process.env.PORT || 3333;
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening on port " + port) );

// ...
// Various app.get(...) endpoints below
// ...
```

However, this is now catching all API requests (for example, I want to make a GET request to `/metric`) and returning `index.html` instead of the correct JSON data.

How do I implement BrowserHistory and have API endpoints?

Comment: You need to define `app.get('*', ...)` after `app.get(...)` for endpoints.

Comment: @TimurBilalov thanks! I didn't realize the order mattered - happy to accept an answer with the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `app.get('*', ...)` after `app.get(...)` for endpoints.

If you take a look at [docs about "middleware"](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), you'll see that express app looks like a layered cake, every layer responsible for something. Each request pass throw all layers. Layer can execute some code, modify `req`, `res` and also can call for `next()` layer.

`app.get('*', ...)` handles all requests and doesn't call `next()` for, so if you define this before other middlewares, they won't be executed.